# Memory allocation with Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management

I am wondering what happen if you declare a local thread within a method? Normally all the local variables will be gone as soon as the function returns since they are all allocated on Stack.  However, it seems that a local thread would be a different story. Is that right?

```
public int A() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        doSomething();
    }
    t.start();
    return -1;
 }
```

Comment: This question is hard to read/understand.  Can you edit it to flesh it out?  Explain better what you are asking.  Show some concise. code samples?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A Thread is its own GC root.  So any time you create a thread despite its creation context it will not be ready to GC until its run method completes.  This is true even if the local method completes and the thread is still alive.

Example:

```
public void doSomeAsync(){
   Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
          Thread.sleep(500);
      }
   });
   th.start();
   //do something else quickly
}
```

After `//do  somethign else quickly` anything defined that did not escape the method is then marked for GC. Thread th will not be marked for GC and is correctly placed on the heap with it's own thread-stack.

Comment: +1 Nice answer John.  Can you show some sample code to elaborate?

Comment: Does it mean that local thread will be placed on the Heap even though it declares as local within a method ?

Comment: @user1389813 Java will do escape analysis to determine if an object can be placed locally on the stack or on the heap.  A Thread inherently escapes and thus would be placed on the heap. You can read on escape analysis here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275/index.html

Answer (score 7):

John's answer is good but I thought I'd add some more details.  Here's a code example that I'll use to show specific variable usage.

```
 public void startThread() {
      long var1 = 10;
      byte[] var2 = new byte[1024];
      final byte[] var3 = new byte[1024];
      final byte[] var4 = new byte[1024];
      Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
          private long var5 = 10;
          private byte[] var6 = new byte[1024];
          public void run() {
              int var7 = 100;
              byte[] var8 = new byte[1024];
              System.out.println("Size of var4 is " + var4.length);
              baz();
              ...
          }
          private void baz() {
              long var9 = 2;
              byte[] var10 = new byte[1024];
              ...
          }
      });
      thread.start();
 }
```

So we have a number of variables here allocated around a thread.  We also have the `Thread` object itself as well as the `Runnable` target the thread is running.

- thread -- Although it looks to be local to `startThread()`, the associated `Thread` is also managed by the JVM.  It is only GC'd after the `run()` method finishes and the `Thread` is reaped by the JVM.  After the `Thread` is GC'd then all of the fields used by the `Thread` can be GC'd.
- Runnable -- This anonymous class is what the thread is running.  It can be GC'd after the `Thread` finishes and is GC'd.
- var1 -- This is local to `startThread()` and allocated on the stack.  It will be overwritten when the `startThread()` method finishes and the stack is reused.
- var2 -- This is local to `startThread()` and allocated on the heap.  It cannot be used by the thread since it is not `final`.  It can be GC'd after `startThread()` finishes.
- var3 -- This is local to `startThread()` and allocated on the heap.  This is `final` so it *could* be used by the thread but it is not.  It can be GC'd after `startThread()` finishes.
- var4 -- This is local to `startThread()` and allocated on the heap.  This is `final` and it is used by the thread.  It can only be GC'd after both the `startThread()` method finishes *and* the `Runnable` and the `Thread` are GC'd.
- var5 -- This is a local field inside of the `Runnable` and allocated on the heap as part of the `Runnable` anonymous class.  It can be GC'd after the `Runnable` finishes and the `Runnable` and the `Thread` are GC'd.
- var6 -- This is a local field inside of the `Runnable` and allocated on the heap.  It can be GC'd after the `Runnable` finishes and the `Runnable` and the `Thread` are GC'd.
- var7 -- This is a local field inside of the `run()` method and allocated on the stack of the new thread.  It will be overwritten when the `run()` method finishes and the stack is reused.
- var8 -- This is a local field inside of the `run()` method and allocated on the heap.  It can be GC'd after the `run()` method finishes.
- var9 -- This is a local field inside of the `baz()` method and allocated on the stack of the new thread.  It will be overwritten when the `baz()` method finishes and the stack is reused.
- var10 -- This is a local field inside of the `baz()` method and allocated on the heap.  It can be GC'd after the `baz()` method finishes.

Couple other notes:

- If the new thread is never started then it can be GC'd once `startThread()` finishes. The `Runnable` and all of the variables associated with it can be GC'd then as well.
- If you have a `final long varX` primitive declared in `startThread()` and used in the thread, then it must be allocated on the heap and *not* the stack.  When `startThread()` finishes it will still be in use.

Comment: var 9 will be allocated on stack of that Anonymous thread, correct ? since each thread has its own stack, but shared the same heap. Also I think in order for inner class (anonymous class) to access the variables on the outer scope, the only way is to declare variable as final, not just because for Thread, correct ?

Comment: Yes, var9 will be on the stack of the new thread.  Same for var7.  I've edited my answer to make that more clear @user1389813.

Comment: @user1389813 If the new thread is never started then it can be GC'd once `startThread()` finishes.  All of the variables associated with it can be GC'd then as well.

Answer (score 0):

If a Thread is started from a local context, the thread will continue to execute until it's Runnable's `run` method has completed execution.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is of a primitive, then it'll be on the stack and will be gone when the method returns -- but your thread's `Runnable` instance (or whatever contains the meat of the thread) will have a copy of that primitive value.

If the variable is of a reference type, then the object is allocated on the heap and lives until there are no more references to it, at which point it's eligible for garbage collection. The *reference* to that object is on the stack and will be gone when the method returns, but as with primitives, the thread's `Runnable` will have a copy of that same reference (and will thus keep that object alive).

Comment: A primitive variable declared inside of a method will be in the stack.  A primitive variable that is a field of a class will be on the heap.

Comment: @Gray Yes, I should have specified non-field variables. I tend to call class/instance variables "fields" to reduce that ambiguity, and while I think that's not uncommon, I agree it's not strictly JLS.

Answer (score -1):

If you spawn a local `Thread` within a method, only the local method variables declared as `final` will stick around until the `Thread` has completed.  When the `Thread` completes its `run()` method, the thread and any final variables it had available to it from the method that created it will get garbage collected like everything else.

**Clarification**

Only `final` variables used within the original method AND the spawned Thread's `run()` method will refrain from being garbage collected until both the method and the `run()` method completes.  If the thread doesn't access the variable, then the presence of the thread will not prevent the variable from being garbage collected after the original method completes.

**References**

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html

Comment: Final has nothing to do with whether a field "sticks around".  Final just affects whether the field can be reassigned and it also impacts constructor assignment ordering.

Comment: Sure it does.  If I have a method that declares a final variable at the top of the method, then spawns a thread that accesses that final variable within its run() method, that final variable will not get garbage collected as long as the Thread is still running, because that final variable is still reachable in the JVM's object graph by the Thread.  This is true regardless of whether the original method that spawned the thread returns before the run() method or not.

Comment: Oh I see.  I thought you were talking about final fields _within_ the Thread.  Please edit your answer to clarify.  Also, I'm not sure you are correct Ben unless the thread actually accesses the final field.  I've verified that with testing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (though I'm too lazy to check the JLS right now) that it's not that the method variable sticks around forever, but rather that it gets copied to an instance variable in the `Runnable`. (And in Java 8, you won't even need to declare method variables as final for that to work -- it's enough that they're unchanged, which is to say, you could have marked them final if you wanted.)

Comment: I think it probably depends on JVM implementation, but the prescribed  behavior spec'ed by Java would be that external access by other objects would determine how long those final variables stuck around.

Comment: @yshavit if the method variable is a deep Object reference with a complex structure, I am certain that at most, the Object's reference is copied to an instance variable in `Runnable` - if the original method decides to modify the contents of the original Object while the `Runnable` is running, the `Runnable` will also see those modifications.

Comment: @BenLawry I'm sure that's the behavior, and in practice I'm nearly sure that's how it's implemented. I'm just not sure if that's actually mandated by the JLS, or if it's allowed by the JLS and also happens to be the only reasonable way to do it.

Comment: By the documentation below, the final variable in the question description would be considered "in use" as long as the Thread maintains a reference to it.  Therefore, if the run() method of the thread accesses it, the variable will not be garbage collected until run() has completed.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html